# Buttons Are Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am new to JQuery DataTables, but I think I followed the guide on how to add the buttons. The display X number of records is now gone, but the buttons are not there. This is my code, what needs to be modified so the buttons will be displayed?

This is my code - but I just noticed I am getting a few errors, dangit

```
buttons.flash.min.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined
    at buttons.flash.min.js:31
    at buttons.flash.min.js:8
    at buttons.flash.min.js:8
(anonymous) @ buttons.flash.min.js:31
(anonymous) @ buttons.flash.min.js:8
(anonymous) @ buttons.flash.min.js:8
buttons.html5.min.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'pdfMake' of undefined
    at buttons.html5.min.js:11
    at buttons.html5.min.js:8
    at buttons.html5.min.js:8
(anonymous) @ buttons.html5.min.js:11
(anonymous) @ buttons.html5.min.js:8
(anonymous) @ buttons.html5.min.js:8
jquery-3.4.1.js:10091 Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.load (jquery-3.4.1.js:10091)
    at script.min.js,qver=2.4.5.pagespeed.ce._4ES8o_qKT.js:1
```

````
<script type="text/javascript">
var information = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;
console.log(JSON.stringify(information[0]));
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#my-table').dataTable({
        data: information,
        columns: [
            { data: 'EmpName' },
            { data: 'NumSales' },
            { 
              data: 'TotalSales', 
              render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(",", ".", 2, '$'),
             },
            { 
              data: 'LMonthSales',
              render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(",", ".", 2, '$'),
            },
            { 
               data: '2MonthSales', 
              render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(",", ".", 2, '$'),
            },
            { 
               data: '3MonthSales', 
              render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(",", ".", 2, '$'),
             },
            { 
               data: '4MonthSales', 
              render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(",", ".", 2, '$'),
            },
            { 
              data: '5MonthSales', 
              render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(",", ".", 2, '$'),
            },
            { 
               data: '6MonthSales',
              render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(",", ".", 2, '$'),
            }
        ],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
           'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    });
});
</script>```
````

Comment: I think you are missing **jszip.js** & **pdfmake.js**.

Comment: See my explanation post regarding your given snippet link https://pastebin.com/Yv58VEgR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on previous post (it was deleted) you shared all javascript and css file included related to Jquery Datatables.

Actually your link contains incomplete/error of HTML link tag. Few of your mistake quoted below:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" script
> src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"</script>
> ```

Your mistakes was:

1. Extra **`script`** inside script tag
2. Missing closing of script tag symbol **`>`** before `</script>`

So the fixed one will like this

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
> src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
> ```

**Run snippet below with fixed link**

```js
var information = [
{"EmpName":"Tiger Nixon","NumSales":100,"TotalSales":100,"LMonthSales":100,"2MonthSales":100},
{"EmpName":"Tiger Nixon","NumSales":100,"TotalSales":100,"LMonthSales":100,"2MonthSales":100},
{"EmpName":"Tiger Nixon","NumSales":100,"TotalSales":100,"LMonthSales":100,"2MonthSales":100}
]

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
           'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ],
        data: information,
        columns: [
            { data: "EmpName",title: "EmpName" },
            { 
              data: "NumSales",
              title: "NumSales", 
              render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(",", ".", 2, '$')
            },
            { 
              data: "TotalSales",
              title: "TotalSales",
              render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(",", ".", 2, '$')
            },
            { 
              data: "LMonthSales",
              title: "LMonthSales",
              render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(",", ".", 2, '$')
            },
            { 
              data: "2MonthSales",
              title: "2MonthSales",
              render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(",", ".", 2, '$')
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: I get this error in consonle when I try your sample above ```jquery
Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
    at w.fn.init.w.fn.load (jquery.min.js:2)
    at script.min.js,qver=2.4.5.pagespeed.ce._4ES8o_qKT.js:1
```

Comment: Okay - upon further analysis it looks like the issue is something to do with the version of jquery I am needing to use for this.

Comment: @HotTomales at least your missing buttons problem solved. You can try https://datatables.net/download/nightly . In some case nightly build version came with bug fixes.

Comment: it actually seems to be the jquery version that DataTables needs to run and the standard jquery files in WordPress not playing nice together.